# Why am I getting a 'Factory not registered' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a model Answer:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :question
end
```

In my Question model, i have defined `has_many :answers`. My Answer model have three column: content (text), question_id (integer), correct(boolean). Default value of `correct` column is `false`.

I created factories to create Answer object:

```
factory :answer do
  content "Content of an answer"
  question

  factory :accept_answer do
    correct true
  end
end
```

In my rspec file, i created new answer object successfully with below code:

```
let(:answer) { FactoryGirl.create(:answer, question: question) }

subject { answer }
its(:correct) { should be_false }
```

But when i used below code to create accept_answer object:

```
describe "an accepted answer" do
  let(:accept_answer) { FactoryGirl.create(:accept_answer, question: question) } 
  it { accept_answer.correct.should be_true }
end
```

It has error

```
Failure/Error: let(:accept_answer) { FactoryGirl.create(:accept_answer, question: question) }
ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: accept_answer
```

I don't know what wrong with my code :(

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem because spork server can't regonize what i changes, so i have restart spork server and it works.